# Errors with moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I'm using to make my CV with the `moderncv` package for the first time. I'm working with TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX 2.9 on Window 7. I've downloaded the new `moderncv` from CTAN ... but got into problems.
I don't know how to fix them.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,naustrian]{moderncv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\moderncvtheme[grey]{classic}
\firstname{My} \familyname{Name} 
\title{CV} 
\address{Street}{somewhere\protect\[0.1em] country\protect\[0.2em]} 
%\mobile{+1231231231323} %\email{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
 %\section{Section} %\cvitem{something}{something} %\cvitem{something}{something} Testtext. 
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Thanks for your responses. I have just compiled your example, but not working yet. Here you can find some lines from .log file :

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

l.2 < !-- saved from url=(0078)http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/macros/lat...

You're in trouble here. Try typing to proceed. If that doesn't work, type X to quit.

Overfull \hbox (28.55835pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--4 []\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95

Overfull \hbox (22.23462pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--4 \OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 from []

Overfull \hbox (447.5515pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--4 \OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 url=(0078)http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/macros/latex/c ontrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty [] }
```

---

Thanks for your responses. I have just compiled your example, but not working yet. 
Here you can find some lines from .log file :

```
{This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.4.16)  16 APR 2013 14:34
entering extended mode
**LaTeX2.tex
(C:\Users\iman\Desktop\moderncv\LaTeX2.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2009-06-19, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, lao, latin, lat
vian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerm
an, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, 
romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swis
sgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, u
senglishmax, welsh, loaded.
(C:\Users\iman\Desktop\moderncv\moderncv.cls
Document Class: moderncv 2013/02/09 v1.3.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter d
ocument class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size11.clo"
File: size11.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.2 <
     !-- saved from url=(0078)http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/macros/lat...

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


Overfull \hbox (28.55835pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--4
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 <!--
Overfull \hbox (25.91501pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--4
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 saved
 []


Overfull \hbox (22.23462pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--4
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 from
 []


Overfull \hbox (447.5515pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--4
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 url=(0078)http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/macros/latex/c
ontrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
 []
 }
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) "I got into problems" is not informative at all. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can update your own answer instead of added the code as a comment.

Comment: How exactly do you compile the example? If you're using `pdflatex` as the log in your answer seems to show, something is wrong with your (La)TeX installation. Try compiling this: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}Hello world!\end{document}`

Comment: Also, make sure you downloaded your TeX files correctly. The log `l.2 < !-- saved from url=(0078)http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/macros/lat...` seems like you are feeding HTML to TeX (saved the code from a web page displaying it maybe?).

Comment: From the posted log file it looks like a problem with your copy of `etoolbox.sty`

Answer (score 2):

You can put code into your question and use the `{}` button, it looks far lore readable than in comments.

You have

```
e\protect\[0.1em] country\protect\[0.2em]}
```

`\[` starts display math mode (which never finds a matching `\]`) You intended

```
e\protect\\[0.1em] country\protect\\[0.2em]}
```

To force a line break

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,naustrian]{moderncv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\moderncvtheme[grey]{classic}
\firstname{My} \familyname{Name} 
\title{CV} 
\address{Street}{somewhere\protect\\[0.1em] country\protect\\[0.2em]} %\mobile{+1231231231323} %\email{}
\begin{document} \maketitle %\section{Section} %\cvitem{something}{something} %\cvitem{something}{something} Testtext. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `\protect` line breaks in the address, but make sure you don't end the group early with `}`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,naustrian]{moderncv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\moderncvtheme[grey]{classic}
\firstname{My} \familyname{Name} 
\title{CV} 
\address{Street\\somewhere\\[0.1em] country\\[0.2em]} %
\mobile{+1231231231323} 
\email{} 

\begin{document} 
\maketitle 

\section{Section} 

\cvitem{something}{something} 
\cvitem{something}{something} 

Test text. 
\end{document}
```